# Pastebinit script will not word wrap

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I found this "googlizer" script that launches my browser and searches using whatever is highlighted on my system as the google search string. I've modified it using pastebinit package here on Ubuntu so that it takes what is highlighted, pipes it to pastebinit (using paste.ubuntu.com), and finally pipes the pastebin url back to the clipboard.

It works well except for the fact that the pasted text comes back a single line.

Here is is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec wish "$0" "$@"

wm withdraw .
if { [catch { set word [selection get "STRING"] }] != 0 } { exit 0 }
regsub -all "( |\n)+" "$word" " " googleWord
exec echo \"$googleWord\" | pastebinit -b http://paste.ubuntu.com | xclip -selection clipboard

exit 0
```

How can I preserve the original pre-script formatting?

Comment: `sh != bash` Also why are you escaping the quotes around `"$googleWord"` (leave it quoted, to prevent expansion/word-splitting issues -- may very well be the problem here). If quoting doesn't fix it, make sure your IFS is correct, e.g. put `IFS=$' \n\t'` at the top of the script. Also possibly do `echo -e` rather than `echo`, though shouldn't matter if it's already processed at that point.

Comment: Sorry, sh script. This is my first time messing with any Linux script. I was escaping out of the quotes because I thought that fixed something before, but apparently it has no effect. Appears to work the same without escaping. Add IFS=$' \n\t' to the very top of above #! /bin/sh ? Tried that but the script wouldn't work with that in there. As you said, echo -e had no effect on the formatting.

Comment: Below the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`), though not sure that will help. Hopefully someone in the [sh] tag can help you, since I don't know what I'm assume is dash well enough to understand where the error is.

Comment: I couldn't get the script to work after inserting the IFS line. Still looking for a fix for word wrapping.